# Web development for smart switches IoT

Tags: python, web, iot, alexa-skills-kit, arduino-esp8266

I have many jinvoo light switches in my house. I control them from the app in my cell or using alexa echo gen 3 and everything works perfect.
Now I am trying to create a local web page that allows me to know the status and to interact with the switches.

I have been looking an api and found nothing. I also thought about creating an Alexa skill to interact with my page or to use and arduino ESP8266.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to control them from a skill, you can create custom tasks for different operations within a skill, then trigger them using Quick Links for Alexa.

Custom tasks: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/implement-custom-tasks-in-your-skill.html

Link to custom tasks from a web page: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/create-a-quick-link-for-your-custom-task.html#